How to add direct dependencies in Android project using Gradle?
I'm working on an Android project where I need to add the osmdroid library for offline map usage. I would like to add the following dependencies directly in my build.gradle file:
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.6'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-wms:6.1.6'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:6.1.6'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-geopackage:6.1.6'

However, my current project is set up to use a libs.*** shorthand for dependencies, like this:
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
...}


so the first one is groovy syntax, u can edit it to be like this and add it to dependencies
implementation ("org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.6")
implementation ("org.osmdroid:osmdroid-wms:6.1.6")
implementation ("org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:6.1.6")
implementation ("org.osmdroid:osmdroid-geopackage:6.1.6")

if u want to use the libs.*** shorthand for dependencies, u can alt+enter and chose to make it  libs.*** shorthand for dependencies

did it worked with u
